# "Unable to start debugging on the web server" error on first time debug attempt

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api

I've searched around (SO and other googling) but couldn't find *anything* that solves this problem.

My solution contains multiple projects: a few libraries, MVC apps, WebAPIs. The issue started to appear on some of the new WebAPI projects created, only 2 projects out of 18.

Whenever I make a code change and try to run the debugger in Visual Studio (Local IIS), I get the following error message:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection
>   was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed
>   by the server

If I click `OK` on that error message and start debugging again, it works fine. So it basically always takes 2 tries to get the debugger running with the latest code.

The app runs under the default website and app pool in IIS, with most of the default settings. Everything in the solution targets .net 461. Visual Studio 2017 is on the latest version (15.7.6) and I also have the latest .NET framework installed. VS is running as administrator.

The issue doesn't seem to be due to a local setup since it also happens with other people running this solution and trying to debug the 2 projects having this problem.

Is there any way to debug this further and figure out why this is happening?

EDIT: <strike>made some progress, the issue seems to happen because something hangs in `Application_Start()`. Upon adding a bunch of logs between each function calls, it seems that the cause is in the registration of the WebAPI, particularly when enabling Swagger through the Swashbuckle NuGetPackage. I'll keep this post open but also raise an issue with Swashbuckle.</strike>

It was a red herring, after a few more replications it hanged at the end of `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`.

Looking at the IIS logs, I see quite a few DEBUG entries like this one:

`2018-08-09 13:32:54 127.0.0.1 DEBUG /MyApp/debugattach.aspx - 80 - 127.0.0.1 - - 401 0 0 7240`

`config.EnsureInitialized()` seems to be one of the possible things that hang, since it is executed at the end of the registration. Not idea yet on a possible cause.

Comment: Disable IIS application pool idle shutdown, or set it to a larger value. Then see if you get some improvement. (Only a guess.)

Comment: I've tried that but the default is already 20 minutes and I can reproduce the issue by debugging -> stopping -> making a small code change + saving -> launching the debugger with new code (build + debug). Setting to a large value or 0 doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: If you make no code change, can you reproduce this issue? If it is code change related, I will check VS Browser Link settings.

Comment: It happens only after a code change, otherwise I can start/stop debugging just fine. So I'm assuming the issue is when "publishing" to the site (not sure about the correct terminology here).

Comment: What does your publish settings look like? Could you edit this post with a copy of what you are using?

Comment: Just a guess. If your application writes something to the bin folder or modifies the web.config in some way and only does that on first start after a code change (for example, write the dll version somewhere that changes only after a code change), that could explain this behaviour, because IIS will restart the app after such a change.

Comment: @AlonCatz isn't it common for an app to do that though? Do you know of a way to make it work without having to wait for the error message the first time?

Comment: @AbrahamLuna when you say "publish settings", is it under the "Web" tab or "Package/Publish Web"? I'm not sure the latter is being used.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint in your WebApiConfig.Register method and check out the state data to see if anything happens that way?

Comment: @AbrahamLuna No breakpoint is hit when trying to debug WebApiConfig.Register, ever. I think this has something to do with the app starting before the debugger is attached.

Comment: So you are not running IIS Express. You installed IIS and have it always running in the backgroud? This doc says that Visual Studio attaches a debugger by loading the pdb files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-tips-and-tricks#get-more-familiar-with-how-the-debugger-attaches-to-your-app

Comment: @AbrahamLuna all our projects are using Local IIS (installed on the machine) for local development, loading each app under the same site, all run in the DefaultAppPool.

Comment: If you add a new WebAPI project to your solution, and then create a simple "Hello World", does it debug just fine? And after a code change?

Comment: @AbrahamLuna I've created a new project with a similar setup but fewer dependencies and so far I've been unable to reproduce the issue, so it looks like it's related to one of the dependencies. I'll try to add things gradually until i find a point where it breaks and try to isolate the culprit this way.

Comment: @RaphaelLaurent any updates please?

Comment: @EARNEST the apps ended up being migrated to .Net Core, which doesn't have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

run visual studio in administrator mode

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on a legacy ASP website. The application had enabled very strict request filtering in the web.config. This had the unintended effect of breaking Visual Studio's ability to attach the debugger to the browser.

The offending lines in our web.config were in the `verbs` node:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>    
        <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
          <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Once I removed them, the error went away and I could run a normal debug session